# Using Response of Confluence Rest API

Tags: python, json, confluence-rest-api

I am performing bulk operation of creating Space and Pages in our Confluence Cloud instance. I am not particularly a programmer. Need some assistance in using the response we are getting after running the APIs using Python. The output is in Json format. If this is the output can you please let me know how can I access the title and ID -

```
{
"content": {
    "id": "398852913",
    "type": "page",
    "status": "current",
    "title": "Test Project Name 1 SOW",
    "childTypes": {},
    "macroRenderedOutput": {},
    "restrictions": {},
    "_expandable": {
        "container": "",
        "metadata": "",
        "extensions": "",
        "operations": "",
        "children": "",
        "history": "/rest/api/content/398852913/history",
        "ancestors": "",
        "body": "",
        "version": "",
        "descendants": "",
        "space": "/rest/api/space/TestSpace1",
    },
    "_links": {
        "webui": "/spaces/TestSpace1/pages/398852913/Test+Project+Name+1++SOW",
        "self": "https://enerzinx.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/398852913",
        "tinyui": "/x/MQPGFw",
    },
},
"title": "Test Project Name 1 SOW",
"excerpt": "file-list",
"url": "/spaces/TestSpace1/pages/398852913/Test+Project+Name+1++SOW",
"resultGlobalContainer": {
    "title": "TestSpace1",
    "displayUrl": "/spaces/TestSpace1",
},
"breadcrumbs": [],
"entityType": "content",
"iconCssClass": "aui-iconfont-page-default",
"lastModified": "2020-06-24T06:17:32.333Z",
"friendlyLastModified": "Jun 24, 2020",
"score": 0.59390986,
}
```

Comment: `title = response["title"]` and `id = response["content"]["id"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your response is a string in JSON format first you will need to parse the JSON into a dictionary. For this you can use the `json` module, which is part of the set of standard modules. After parsing the JSON you can then access the keys using a dictionary lookup.

```py
>>> import json
>>>
>>> json_string = '{"foo": "bar"}'
>>> json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
>>> json_dict["foo"]
'bar'
```

It looks like your response JSON will yield a nested dictionary, so the path for the title will look something like `json_dict["foo"]["bar"]`.

Comment: Thanks @Dylan for responding. This is part of the response output I am getting " {'results': [{'content': {'id': '398852905', 'type': 'page', 'status': 'current', 'title': 'Test Project Name 1  PT', 'childTypes': {}," with my code. I tried including json.loads statement "res = json.loads(response.text) resJsonDict = json.loads(res) . It throws this error " raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '" Please let me know what am I missing.

Comment: If you are using the `requests` library you should be able to call `res.json()` as well to parse the JSON. Looking at the result object this request gives you a list of results, although it does look like that JSON is incomplete. Based on what I can see you can try `response["results"][0]["content"]["title"]` and `response["results"][0]["content"]["id"]`, where `response` is the parsed JSON response and `0` is the index of the result that you are reading the title and ID of.

Comment: Thanks @Dylan - Was able to achieve what I was trying using  "pageID = str(res['results'][i]['content']['id'])"